# issue with docker.withDockerRegistry() in jenkins pipeline

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to push docker images to ecr repo via jenkins which is installed on kubernetes, I have created everything i.e. docker images & ECR repo. I have a jenkins pipeline script which will pull docker image and push the image to ECR. I am using the code

```
stage('Push image to ECR'){     
docker.withRegistry("https://807***16.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/helloworld", "ecr:us-east-1:ecr") {
                           docker.image('faisalbasha82/helloworld').push('latest')
              }
}
```

Iam getting the following error which I think is related to the environment path not being correct to get to the docker command.

````
[Pipeline] { (Push image to ECR)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u AWS -p ******** https://807***16.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/helloworld
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-0-28-170.ec2.internal/10.0.28.170:47472
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:1060)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
        at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:466)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.impl.RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.materialize(RegistryKeyMaterialFactory.java:101)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.AbstractEndpointStepExecution2.doStart(AbstractEndpointStepExecution2.java:53)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$run$0(GeneralNonBlockingStepExecution.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:250)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:219)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1319)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1272)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE```
````

Comment: The `/helloworld` looks odd in your ECR URL.

Comment: how did you resolve?

Comment: Is this resolved? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

The Jenkins plugin requires the `docker` binary to be present on the host the agent executing the node script is running on.  The error you see, is what is reported when the binary is not present.  You most likely need to have Docker installed.